# Kubernetes install gen_deepcopy permission denied

Tags: makefile, kubernetes, archlinux

From a fresh clone of the repo, upon running `make release` I greeted with this error:

```
./hack/run-in-gopath.sh: line 33: _output/bin/deepcopy-gen: Permission denied
!!! Error in ./hack/run-in-gopath.sh:33
  '"${@}"' exited with status 1
Call stack:
  1: ./hack/run-in-gopath.sh:33 main(...)
Exiting with status 1
make: *** [Makefile.generated_files:201: gen_deepcopy] Error 1
```

Comment: That error makes it sound like you don't have permission to write to the `_output/bin` directory. Can you delete the `_output` directory (if it exists) and then check that your umask?

Comment: @RobertBailey I tried that to no avail, difficult one this.

Comment: I'm getting a similar error building from head (on a mac with go 1.6.3).

Comment: What platform (mac, windows, linux) are you using?

Comment: @RobertBailey I'm on Arch Linux running Go 1.6.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bunch of stuff changed with the build recently, so please first try 'sudo make clean' and if you still get errors, let me know.

Comment: This has fixed it on release v1.3.3 - I'm yet to try at head.

Comment: Didn't work for me as of 1.5.1.
`$ sudo make clean
+++ [1215 10:22:35] Verifying Prerequisites....
+++ [1215 10:22:36] Removing _output directory

$ KUBE_BUILD_PLATFORMS=windows/amd64 make WHAT=cmd/kube-dns
(...)
+++ [1215 10:22:49] Building go targets for windows/amd64:
    cmd/libs/go2idl/deepcopy-gen
./hack/run-in-gopath.sh: line 33: _output/bin/deepcopy-gen: Permission denied
Makefile.generated_files:237: recipe for target 'gen_deepcopy' failed
make[1]: *** [gen_deepcopy] Error 1
Makefile:438: recipe for target 'generated_files' failed
(...)`

Comment: I have got `recipe for target 'gen_deepcopy' failed` error too but for my case this is caused by too small memory allocation. Actually I was using DigitalOcean but it failed with 512MB droplet, and succeeded with 3GB droplet without changing any configuration except for the droplet size.